# How to get CUDA compute capability of a GPU in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, cuda

The question is very simple: One of my users encountered an error in pytorch:

```
Found GPU0 NVIDIA GeForce GT 710 which is of cuda capability 3.5.
PyTorch no longer supports this GPU because it is too old.
The minimum cuda capability supported by this library is 3.7.
```

This means I cannot rely on `torch.cuda.is_available()` to check whether it can actually run my code. I need to also make sure the CUDA compute capability of the GPU is >= 3.7. Yet, for some strange reason, the seemingly simple task of getting a GPU's CUDA compute capability is nowhere to be found on stack overflow or Google, despite that right there in the error message it seems to get it no problem.

Comment: I find the [Cuda Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#GPUs_supported) to be the best resource for determining compute capability.

Comment: My question was about how to determine it programmatically so it won't crash when my user runs it.

Google research returned tons of irrelevant results and it took me a long time to find the answer. On a whim I tried chatGPT and it answered instantly and correctly. Seems like Google search is not good these days.

Also, according to your wikipedia page, cuda 11 supports capability 3.5, but my error message says minimum supported is 3.7.

I'm also a little confused why support for less powerful GPU's is dropped outright, since (IIUC) cuda capability just refers to how fast they can run it

Comment: @pete: The limitations you see with compute capability are imposed by the people that build and maintain Pytorch, not the underlying CUDA toolkit. They have chosen for it to be like this. Also, compute capability isn't a performance metric, it is (as the name implies) a hardware feature set/capability metric.

Answer (score 4):

What I did not realize is that the "major" and "minor" of `torch.cuda.get_device_properties(0)` is actually the CUDA compute capability. For example, if major is 7 and minor is 5, cuda capability is 7.5. It can also be done via `get_device_capability`.